# how to show aside inside of template not in main page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular-strap

i am using aside component of angularstrap and I create aside dynamically using this code snippet :

```
var aside=$aside({"title":"aside test", 
    "backdrop": false , 
    "placement": "left" ,
    "content":"<h1>this is aside in angularjs</h1><p>it work fine!!!</p> "
}); 
$scope.showAside = function(){
  aside.$promise.then(function() {
  aside.show();
});
```

but when i call showAside() function and aside appear in page and i change the route and template change to another content aside still is visible. this seems this aside is added to main page but 
i want add this aside to child template.